# java.lang.StackOverflowError while using a RegEx to Parse big strings

Tags: java, regex, stack-overflow

This is my Regex

```
((?:(?:'[^']*')|[^;])*)[;]
```

It tokenizes a string on semicolons. For example,

```
Hello world; I am having a problem; using regex;
```

Result is three strings

```
Hello world
I am having a problem
using regex
```

But when I use a large input string I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4078)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: How big is the string you are parsing?

Comment: The question is quite old, however i could resolved a similar issue using possessive quentifier (`*+` instead `*`) to avoid backtracking

Comment: Also i should use atomic group `(?>..)` instead of group `(?:..)` always to prevent backtracking

Answer (score 66):

Unfortunately, Java's builtin regex support has problems with regexes containing repetitive alternative paths (that is, `(A|B)*`). This is compiled into a recursive call, which results in a StackOverflow error when used on a very large string.

A possible solution is to rewrite your regex to not use a repititive alternative, but if your goal is to tokenize a string on semicolons, you don't need a complex regex at all really, just use [String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with a simple `";"` as the argument.

Comment: Most regex engines will have this problem.

Comment: I think I didn't put up my case clearly, sorry for that. String is not tokenized just on semicolon but it will be tokenized on many patterns at the same time, tokenizing on semicolon was just one simple case.

Comment: @Ali well, generally speaking: try to avoid alternatives in a wildcard. You could also give alternative regex libraries such as jregex a go, though I'm not sure that would solve the issue...

Comment: @NullUserException Not JavaScript at least. I'm doing the same on a string with 1600+ chars. It gives me StackOverflowError in Java. And yet JavaScript gives me the correct result within 1 ms. Tbh I'm really appalled by how a compiled language, with all its possible optimization, could perform worse, in terms of performance, than an interpreted language in this simple task. You could try this yourself (browser console in F12): `function test(str){console.time("test");console.log(/^([^']|'[^']*')*'[^']*$/.test(str));console.timeEnd("test")}` then `test("1000+ char string")`

Answer (score 24):

If you really need to use a regex that overflows your stack, you can increase the size of your stack by passing something like -Xss40m to the JVM.

Comment: Increasing stack size via Xss property will increase possibility of OutOfMemoryError. Though it will fix current issue. Rather than increasing Xss refer top answer.

Comment: Helped me in solving a stack overflow error i am seeing while launching the eclipse . 

The error i was seeing was  Could not create content describer for org.robotframework.red.robotsuitefile_robot. Content type has been disabled.
java.lang.StackOverflowError

Answer (score 9):

It might help to add a `+` after the `[^;]`, so that you have fewer repetitions.

Isn't there also some construct that says “if the regular expression matched up to this point, don't backtrace”? Maybe that comes in handy, too. (Update: it is called [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)).

A completely different alternative is to write a utility method called `splitQuoted(char quote, char separator, CharSequence s)` that explicitly iterates over the string and remembers whether it has seen an odd number of quotes. In that method you could also handle the case that the quote character might need to be unescaped when it appears in a quoted string.

```
'I'm what I am', said the fox; and he disappeared.
'I\'m what I am', said the fox; and he disappeared.
'I''m what I am', said the fox; and he disappeared.
```