# StackOverFlowError When Trying To View Graphical Layout For All XML Files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

Yesterday the graphical layout was working fine for the xml files from my app but today whenever I try to view the graphical layout for any xml file I get this error:

```
main.xml: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError

java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Pattern.java:1969)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1851)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1769)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1477)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1150)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:840)
at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2304)
at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2346)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.findResValue(ResourceResolver.java:206)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:325)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
at ...
```

And it keeps going repeating the line:
    com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)

Can Anyone Help?

Comment: Can you please post all relevant code (i.e. XML, Activity that calls, etc...)

Comment: It happens with all of my xml files and I posted the full error.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing (without the code posted here) there is a problem with your `RegEx`. There may be repetitive alternating `RegEx` paths that causes `StackOverflowError` due to recursive calls. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509905/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-while-using-a-regex-to-parse-big-strings) question and try to post your code if possible.

Comment: I am a noob when it comes to android and I have no idea what to do or what caused it...

Comment: Post your code here. Are you matching strings for a particular pattern?