# java.lang.StackOverflowError at at java.util.regex.Pattern in liferay

Tags: java, liferay-6

I am  using liferay 6.1 CE GA2  on 64 bit centos 6 and tomcat 7

When i edit some fields of user and click on save button the page goes to loading state and stay in same state several minute.

if i wait till one minute and  after that  go back to back step by clicking on  "user and organization"  link in control panel and again back to user information then can see that changes is saved .

when i check log file (tomcat/logs/catalina.out) i see the same error :

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-80-exec-83" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4078)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4078)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4078)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4078)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4078)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4078)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4078)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3345)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
```

this problem had occurred  in dynamic data list , when in control panel i wanted to see records
this problem solved by installing oracle jdk 6 , what david suggest me.

But the same problem is occurring on very operation (often on  saving user changes in control panel )

I have serious  challenge with this problem for six month :(
Any help please

Comment: Take a look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509905/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-while-using-a-regex-to-parse-big-strings). It might help some.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss16m" 
or
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss1024m" 
add this property to setenv in tomcat> bin folder