# Is there any method to identify whether a string contains HTML tags in java

Tags: java, html, string

Is there any predefined method stating whether a string contains HTML tags or characters in it?

Comment: No. What's your actual problem, there's probably a better solution for it.

Comment: You could try using something like `JSoup` on your string and see if the length changes.  If no change in length, then it implies that the string contains no HTML.

Comment: `JSoup` is a pretty good HTML parser  bud it depends on what is your purpose of finding the HTML code inside a String ...

Comment: In my scenario, I am getting various string objects at run time. The string might or might not contain HTML tags within. By HTML Tags I mean not necessarilly the string will start with <html> and end with </html> but it can be something like this: `<br/>Test Plan: YTL Test Plan for Release 1<br/><br/>Test Case: Clarity TC - Provisioning 1<br/>`  I need to parse the html contained string to normal string

Answer (score 15):

You can try regular expressions, like this

```
private static final String HTML_PATTERN = "<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>";
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(HTML_PATTERN);

public boolean hasHTMLTags(String text){
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

Comment: think your method needs to be 
    pattern.matcher(text).find()

Comment: Note that regular expressions that contain repetitive alternative paths (ie. (A|B)*) can run into StackOverflowErrors. See this question/answers for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509905/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-while-using-a-regex-to-parse-big-strings

Answer (score 7):

Either Use regular expression to search or identify the HTML tags in String.

```
boolean containsHTMLTag = stringHtml.matches(".*\\<[^>]+>.*");
```

Or as Tim suggested use Jsoup like below:-

```
String textOfHtmlString = Jsoup.parse(htmlString).text();
boolean containedHTMLTag = !textOfHtmlString.equals(htmlString);
```

Comment: regarding the regex, I have two questions: first of all, souldn't you escape the closing ">" like this `".*\\<[^>]+\\>.*"` and second, it seems like an xml doc will also fit this regex

Comment: I will tryout Jsoup and confirm

Comment: The Jsoup method works great but be aware that it will flag any string with extra white space in it.

Comment: jsoup wont work. Parse removes new lines as well. So you could get a false positive

Comment: JSOUP doesnt work - when I pass "aaaa" it gives an HTML output - So the length check will always pass

Answer (score 1):

You should use find()

```
private static final String HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>";

static Pattern htmlValidator = TextUtils.isEmpty(HTML_TAG_PATTERN) ? null:Pattern.compile(HTML_TAG_PATTERN);

public static boolean validateHtml(final String text){
    if(htmlValidator !=null)
      return htmlValidator.matcher(text).find();
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing String with Regex in order to search for HTML (in my case to prevent XSS attack related input) is not the proper way.

A good way to achieve it is by using `Spring HtmlUtils`

Both are better explained already here,

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112495/preventing-xss-attacks-in-a-spring-mvc-application-controller

Comment: This is not the best way to do it,it will also escape for the same characters if the string includes it. It's a false positive.
i.e "!@#$%^&*()" it will produce a different string, which is false positive..