# Save thread after StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I'm using `Spring Boot` with `RabbitMQ`. In some cases my consumer threads (`SimpleMessageListenerContainer`) get aborted because of `StackOverflowError`. I was thinking of catching these kind of errors in order to save the threads and not having to restart my application every time this happens.

1. Is a thread that went through that error in a state that can keep working or should I let it die?
2. If I should let it die, how can I replenish the pool thread used by `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit`?

I know that in general we shouldn't catch `Error` throwables, but I want to know what would happen in this particular case if I did.

**Update**

In the end I just performed the actions that would cause such a behaviour in a separate thread using `Future` and masked (catch and rethrow) any throwable as a `RuntimeException`. This way I could handle the exception in my consumer thread that remained clean. Not the most performant way of dealing with this, but it works great so far and performance has not been an issue.

Comment: What is the root cause for the `StackOverflowError`s?

Comment: Looks like an X Y problem to me, rather than trying to catch `StackOverflowError`, you should try to find the root cause and stop it from happening. A `StackOverflowError` is not a normal thing to happen.

Comment: The root cause are regexes. Of course I will investigate and fix the problem for that particular input, but that won't protect the stability of my application for inputs that I haven't thought of. I'm just trying to be proactive.

Comment: If it's due to the regex being applied on a very large string, perhaps a better solution would be to increase the stack size with the `-Xss` flag. This allows you to keep your application running normally, though you will have to find out what the proper stack size should be. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509905/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-while-using-a-regex-to-parse-big-strings

Comment: I'm already doing this. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: I think it's no good idea to catch an *Error* (except for logging and rethrow). Have a look at this other question: [Differences between Exception and Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-between-exception-and-error).