# regex/java stackoverflow error

Tags: java, regex

The following regex removes lists and menus from webpage text

```
String s = fileContent.replaceAll("(([A-Za-z&—:\\-\\/\\d ])*(\\n|\\r|\\r\\n)){5,}","");
```

It has worked no problem on tens of thousands of files. Today, it gave me a stackoverflow:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5251)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5251)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5251)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5251)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3776)     at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:4435)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match(Pattern.java:4405)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)     at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:4485)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match(Pattern.java:4405)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)

The file it was parsing has hundreds of consecutive \r\n. Other than that, I can't see anything unusual.
Can someone advise as to what aspect of the expression and/or the java internal regex parsing caused the error?

Comment: I believe this answers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509905/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-while-using-a-regex-to-parse-big-strings

Comment: That's it!   Funny it didn't come up when I searched. Thanks a million

Comment: You're welcome. Very interesting case.

Comment: What happens if you replace `(\\n|\\r|\\r\\n)` with `(\\n|\\r\\n?)` to reduce the number of alternative paths?