# Regex for multiline string literals produces `StackOverflowError`

Tags: java, regex, scala, stack-overflow

I want to match strings enclosed in triple `"`-quotes which may contain line breaks, and which don't contain any `"""`-substrings except at the very beginning and in the very end.

Valid example:

```
"""foo
bar "baz" blah"""
```

Invalid example:

```
"""foo bar """ baz"""
```

I tried using the following regex (as Java `String` literal):

```
"(?m)\"\"\"(?:[^\"]|(?:\"[^\"])|(?:\"\"[^\"]))*\"\"\""
```

and it seems to work on short examples. However, on longer examples, like on a string consisting of thousand lines with `hello world`, it gives me a `StackOverflowError`.

**Scala snippet to reproduce the error**

```
import java.util.regex.{Pattern, Matcher}

val text = "\"" * 3 + "hello world \n" * 1000 + "\"" * 3
val p = Pattern.compile("(?m)\"\"\"(?:[^\"]|(?:\"[^\"])|(?:\"\"[^\"]))*\"\"\"")
println(p.matcher("\"\"\" foo bar baz \n baz bar foo \"\"\"").lookingAt())
println(p.matcher(text).lookingAt())
```

(note: test locally, Scastie times out; or maybe reduce 1000 to smaller number?).

**Java snippet that produces the same error**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class RegexOverflowMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
    bldr.append("\"\"\"");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      bldr.append("hello world \n");
    }
    bldr.append("\"\"\"");
    String text = bldr.toString();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)\"\"\"(?:[^\"]|(?:\"[^\"])|(?:\"\"[^\"]))*\"\"\"");
    System.out.println(p.matcher("\"\"\" foo bar baz \n baz bar foo \"\"\"").lookingAt());
    System.out.println(p.matcher(text).lookingAt());
  }
}
```

**Question**

Any idea how to make this "stack safe", i.e. can someone find a regex that accepts the same language, but does not produce a `StackOverflowError` when fed to the Java regex API?

I don't care whether the solution is in Scala or Java (or whatever), as long the same underlying Java regex library is used.

Comment: This here definitely looks somewhat useful: [why `(A|B)*` results in recursive calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7510006/2707792). Note however that for example `"(?m)\"\"\"(?:\"?\"?[^\"])*\"\"\""` suffers from the same errors, even though it doesn't contain alternatives `|`.

Comment: Must the `"""` be at the start and the end of the string? And why not just write it manually? It would just take a few lines more and would be much faster

Comment: @x4rf41 Yes, three double-quotes, followed by whatever characters, as long as there are no triple-double-quotes, then again three double-quotes in the very end. I'd prefer to have a regex that does this, because it would fit nicely into the existing framework. Otherwise, I'd have to invent some "generalized regular language accepting interface" -- this is what I want to avoid, if possible.

Comment: ... and maybe I should explicitly exclude the corner-cases like `"""""""` (seven double-quotes), representing a string literal with a single double quote. Assume that all double quotes inside the string are separated from the starting `"""` and ending `"""` by some other characters. I don't care whether those strange corner-cases are accepted or rejected.

Comment: try this one `^"""((?!""")[\s\S])*"""$` (without the multiline flag). It works here: https://regex101.com/ with both of your examples as expected. it uses a negative look ahead instead. that should prevent the stack overflow i hope (not sure though). escaped: `^\"\"\"((?!\"\"\")[\\s\\S])*\"\"\"$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using a negative look-ahead to basically find a string that starts with `"""` and end with `"""` and contains content that does not include `"""`

As Plain regex: `^"""((?!""")[\s\S])*"""$`

As Java escaped regex: `"^\"\"\"((?!\"\"\")[\\s\\S])*\"\"\"$`"

`\s\S` includes line-break (its basically `.` + line-break or `.` with single line flag)

This should be used without the multiline flag so that `^` and `$` match the start and end of the string and not the start and end of the line

otherwise this:

`""" ab
"""abc"""
abc """`

would match

Also i used this as reference for how to exclude the `"""`: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: just for clarification i added an example where the multiline flag produces problems. you should not use it

Comment: @jwvh Any text with a dollar sign would stop matching.

Comment: @Andreas; You're right. My bad. Forgot about meaning-adjustment inside `[ ]`.

Answer (score 2):

The full answer below optimizes the regex performance, but to prevent stack overflow, as a simple solution, just make the repeating group **possessive**.

Non-possessive repeating groups with choices need recursive calls to allow backtracking. Making it possessive fixes the problem, so simply add a `+` after the `*`:

`"(?m)\"\"\"(?:[^\"]|(?:\"[^\"])|(?:\"\"[^\"]))*+\"\"\""`

---

Also note that if you want to match entire input, you need to call [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--), not [`lookingAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt--).

---

**Performance boost**

*Note: A quick performance test showed this to be more than **6 times faster** than regex in [answer by x4rf41](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50710395/5221149).*

Instead of matching one of

- Not a quote: `[^\"]`
- Exactly one quote: `(?:\"[^\"])`
- Exactly two quotes: `(?:\"\"[^\"])`

in a loop, first match everything up to a quote. If that is a single- or double-quote, but not a triple-quote, match the 1-2 quotes then everything up to next quote, repeat as needed. Finally match the ending triple-quote.

That matching is definitive, so make the repeats possessive. This also prevent stack overflow in case input has many embedded quotes.

```
"{3}          match 3 leading quotes
[^"]*+        match as many non-quotes as possible (if any) {possesive}
(?:           start optional repeating group
   "{1,2}       match 1-2 quotes
   [^"]++       match one or more non-quotes (at least one) {possesive}
)*+           end optional repeating group                  {possesive}
"{3}          match 3 trailing quotes
```

Since you don't use `^` or `$`, there is no need for `(?m)` ([MULTILINE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE))

As Java string:

`"\"{3}[^\"]*+(?:\"{1,2}[^\"]++)*+\"{3}"`